# How to know if a datagram packet was sent to a client

Tags: java, network-programming, udp

I am trying to establish UDP network between processes, where they continuously share messages. I need to know if there is a message pending to be received by a certain process. And if there isn't, what happens when I call the DatagramSocket.receive() function? Will the program halt waiting for the message or it will just ignore this function?
I don't know if I am clear enough or even thinking in the right direction, so any hints will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is from oracle API(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket))

Receives a datagram packet from this socket. When this method returns, the DatagramPacket's buffer is filled with the data received. The datagram packet also contains the sender's IP address, and the port number on the sender's machine.

**This method blocks until a datagram is received**. The length field of the datagram packet object contains the length of the received message. If the message is longer than the packet's length, the message is truncated.

If there is a security manager, a packet cannot be received if the security manager's checkAccept method does not allow it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So there is no way for checking whether a message is pending other than blocking the process. Well, I guess I'll have to switch to TCP, although in my application I don't care if the message is lost.

Comment: @WaleedLutfi With TCP you'll be blocked on the socket input stream `read()` as well.

Comment: @WaleedLutfi Any reason you can't use `java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel` in non-blocking mode? That would be how you read/write a UDP socket asynchronously.

Comment: @Dev You mean 'non-blockingly'. Asynchronous I/O is another whole ball of twine.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for [`DatagramSocket#receive()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive%28java.net.DatagramPacket%29) states

> This method blocks until a datagram is received.

In other words, your current thread stops execution. It will be notified when a datagram is received by the underlying socket.